# Display some html until final page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, angularjs

I am using rails to make a search request.

The search form's action is a certain path "/results/foo" .. which hits a controller that does some validation of input and then redirects to "results/foobar" if search-text was clean.

```
<h1 class="center"><progress style="font-size: 160%;">Loading...</progress></h1>
```

I'd like to show the above html.. and only the above html (either in a view or via jquery) until "results/foobar" has fully loaded.

Is there a way to show such a progress bar animation (html) until final page has completed loading?

More Details (The search bar page has code like this):

```
<form class="form-search" action="/s_results/iscan" method="POST">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input name="searchtext" type="text" class="span4 search-query" placeholder="Type number here...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">
                <i class="icon-search"></i>
                Search
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What you're talking about involves AJAX, and is really more of a JS question, although your backend will need to respond with useful data. Maybe provide a bit more information as to what kind of progress you're dealing with.

Comment: Hi @NathanLilienthal , I'm just looking to display the above html [<progress style="font-size: 160%;">Loading...</progress>] either as an overlay (high z-index) .. or some other method until I have loaded my final page.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, I thought you were looking to update the progress.

Comment: also updated question to add "javascript" tag.. I might do a bounty on this one soon!

Answer (score 0):

What you do in such cases is keep a full window occupying div over your content while your data loads in the background http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/qfrJE/:

```
.busyPanel {
    /* absolute position all over */
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    /* Remove any defaults */
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Make sure it stays on top */
    z-index: 2500;
    /* any image */
    background: grey;
    /* initial visibility */
    display: visible;
}
```

And then remove it when you are done loading:

```
$(".busyPanel").fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but you are using setTimeout(function(){
    $(".busyPanel").fadeOut('slow');
},2000); .. how do I translate that line to simulate a page load? $(window).load(function () {}); happens too late and so does #(document).ready.. is there any other way?

Comment: Load your data via ajax e.g $.get and hide the panel in the on success function.

Comment: So sorry for being an AJAX dummy but which view file (in rails) would contain the "$.get" javascript? the search bar view? or the search-results view?.. also my project has the complexity of an intermediate controller between the search-bar page and the search-results page.. this one exists to validate search input and redirect to search-results page..

Comment: Overview: In rails you need to use format.json from your controller to return json and then call this with jquery $.get and load it into the DOM.

Comment: sorry for the bother again.. but which controller? searchBarController -> searchValidateController -> searchResultsController (which renders the final results)... "-> = redirects to".

Comment: searchResultsController . Instead of rendering you return Json. And render with javascript. Use something like https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender for rendering.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27816/discussion-between-sambehera-and-basarat-ali)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use some JS on click of the link that of entry of the form that shows your `div` then it'll be on the screen while your request processes, once the search is complete and your new page is rendered it'll be gone.

```
-- html
<div class="progress">Loading...</div>

-- css
.progress { display: none; }

-- js
$('#search').click(function() {
  $('.progress').show();
  window.location.href = 'foo';
});
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXmrn/), Simple and easy.

Comment: you mean I have to do the validation of input (making sure its numbers) in the frontend in javascript rather than the backend?

Comment: no, I'm illustrating how you can display a loading div while you load a page.

Comment: I tried this.. the "loading..." text disappears as soon as my controller begins redirecting to the search results page. (/results/foobar).. I, however, want to keep showing that div "while" /results/foobar is being loaded.

Comment: This is actually working, just you need to use javascript to do the navigation. I'm not sure why you are having a problem with this. CAn you post some of your code to gist or something?

Comment: I have many interlinked files.. which particular part would you recommend which makes most sense for a gist? One or both of the controllers? or one or all of the 3 views that im using?